# React/NextJS Handle Option Selected Property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on a website and had a fairly dynamic select box I have been working with. I am fairly new to React in general, and while the select box is working in terms of the functionality of my app...I cannot seem to be able to find a good way to add the selected property to an option once it has been selected. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this? Here is what I am working with (I didn't create the component for "activeProp" yet):

```
import styles from '../../styles/Components/SubFilterSelect.module.scss';

const SubFilterSelect = (props) => {

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value
    props.subFunc(value)
  }

  const Application = (props) => {
    if(props.item && props.item.data.parent_category === 'Application'){
      return(
        <option value={props.item.id}>{props.item.data.name}</option>
      )
    } else{
      return null
    }
  }

  const Benefit = (props) => {
    if(props.item && props.item.data.parent_category === 'Benefit'){
      return(
        <option value={props.item.id}>{props.item.data.name}</option>
      )
    } else{
      return null
    }
  }

  const ReturnCategories = () => {
    if(props.activeApp){
      return(
        <select onChange={handleChange} defaultValue={'DEFAULT'}>
          <option value='DEFAULT'>Choose a Category</option>
          {props.categories.map((category,key) => 
            <Application key={key} item={category} />
          )}
        </select>
      )
    } else if(props.activeBenefit){
      return(
        <select onChange={handleChange} defaultValue={'DEFAULT'}>
          <option value='DEFAULT'>Choose a Category</option>
          {props.categories.map((category,key) => 
            <Benefit key={key} item={category} />
          )}
        </select>
      )
    } else if(props.activeProp){
      return(
        <select onChange={handleChange} defaultValue={'DEFAULT'}>
          <option value='DEFAULT'>Choose a Category</option>
          {props.categories.map((category,key) => 
            {category.data.parent_category === 'Property' ? 
              <option key={key} id={category.id}>{category.data.name}</option>
            : ''}
          )}
        </select>
      )
    } else{
      return(
        <select defaultValue={'DEFAULT'}>
          <option value='DEFAULT'>Choose a Filter Above</option>
        </select>
      )
    }
  }

  return(
    <section className={styles.filterSection}>
      <ReturnCategories />
    </section>
  )
}

export default SubFilterSelect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Firstly** , You should avoid nesting components inside the parent component. It becomes harder to maintain code as it grows. Instead you should adopt code-splitting.
2. **Secondly**, you can use ternary operators instead of `if(s)` as they are much cleaner.
3. **Thirdly**, you can avoid writing `props` multiple times by destructuring arguments [Destructuring Assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
4. **Fourthly**, adopt *DRY principle*  (don't repeat yourself).

Your code should be something like this:

```
import styles from '../../styles/Components/SubFilterSelect.module.scss';

const SubFilterSelect = ({subFunc, activeApp , activeBenefit , activeProp}) => {

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value
    subFunc(value)
  }

  
  return(
    <section className={styles.filterSection}>
      <ReturnCategories handleChange={handleChange}
       activeApp={activeApp} activeProp={activeProp} activeBenefit={activeBenefit}/>
    </section>
  )
}

const ReturnCategories = ({handleChange , activeApp , activeBenefit , activeProp}) =>{
    return(
        <select onChange={handleChange} defaultValue={'DEFAULT'}>

          <option value='DEFAULT'>Choose a Category</option>

          {categories.map((category,key) => {
              return(
                activeApp ? <Application key={key} item={category} /> :

                activeBenefit ? <Benefit key={key} item={category} /> : 

                activeProp  && category.data.parent_category === 'Property' ?
                    <option key={key} id={category.id}>{category.data.name}</option> :
                
                <option value='DEFAULT'>Choose a Filter Above</option>
              )
          }
            
          )}
        </select>
    )
}


const Application = ({item}) => {
    if(item && item.data.parent_category === 'Application'){
      return(
        <option value={item.id}>{item.data.name}</option>
      )
    } else{
      return null
    }
  }
  
  const Benefit = ({item}) => {
    if(item && item.data.parent_category === 'Benefit'){
      return(
        <option value={item.id}>{item.data.name}</option>
      )
    } else{
      return null
    }
  }

  

export default SubFilterSelect
```

Comment: Wow! You learn something new every day. I have honestly never used a string of ternary operators like this before...VERY cool. Sometimes you just need a different perspective and another set of eyes. Thank you very much for the help!